# How to shuffle a column in MySql

Tags: mysql, shuffle

After failing to find anything that matched my needs, I wrote this code to consistently shuffle the values of a column in mysql. Is there a better way to do this?

```
**Original table:**
+----+-----------+
| id | fname     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | mike      |
|  2 | ricky     |
|  3 | jane      |
|  4 | august    |
|  6 | dave      |
|  9 | Jérôme    |
+----+-----------+

**Possible output:**
+----+-----------+
| id | fname     |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | dave      |
|  2 | jane      |
|  3 | mike      |
|  4 | ricky     |
|  6 | Jérôme    |
|  9 | august    |
+----+-----------+

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS shuffle1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS shuffle2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE shuffle1 (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id), original_values varchar(255), key original_values(original_values) );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE shuffle2 (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (id), original_ids int(11), key original_ids(original_ids) );
INSERT INTO shuffle1 (id, original_values) SELECT NULL, table1.fname FROM table1 ORDER BY rand();
INSERT INTO shuffle2 (id, original_ids) SELECT NULL, table1.id FROM table1;
UPDATE table1 SET table1.fname = (SELECT shuffle1.original_values FROM shuffle1 JOIN shuffle2 ON shuffle2.id = shuffle1.id WHERE table1.id = shuffle2.original_ids);
```

Comment: What is your objective here?

Comment: Data sanitisation: let's say you have a production table containing your client list with two columns - first_name and last_name, you want to use it in your test environment but this information is sensitive. shuffling one of the column maintains all the original values and the privacy of your users.

Comment: What you might do is duplicate the entire database, then scramble the values of certain columns, replace them with random data. What you're doing here is rather confusing to say the least.

Comment: That is one approach - but it's very slow with large amounts of data. But the real benefit in keeping the original values instead of randomising the data, is that you know that your tests cover your real-life situations (e.g. special characters, etc) and not some random data based on assumptions a developer made.

Comment: I'm not sure when you say you're preserving the initial values *and* concealing sensitive information. Either the data's in the database, or it isn't. If you're shipping database dumps to developers, make sure the randomized data is structurally equivalent to real data. That is, make the character probabilities similar to what's in your actual data, and the string lengths are also in an equivalent distribution curve.

Comment: I don't see how scrambling is any slower than what you're proposing here with these "shuffle" tables. The best practice here is to completely strip out any sensitive data so it simply is not present in the database dump you give to a developer for testing. To do anything less is self-defeating.

Comment: Re-redited the posting to be clearer:
1. This posting is not about why we need this solution. It's about the solution itself - how to shuffle a column in mysql.
2. I explained thoroughly how scrambling the data helps me - you can find more details about this solution here (http://www.datamasker.com/datasanitization_whitepaper.pdf), as well as other articles online:

Comment: 3. Generating random data requires handling every column according to its type and possible values (int, string+encoding, dates, etc). Shuffling data around is a generic solution with quick maintenance.

Comment: If you're just randomly switching values, you're not sanitizing at all. There's still email addresses and other personally identifying data in the database. Either scrub it, or don't bother. Either you have developers which are authorized to view the production database, in which case they can just use a dump, or you have those that don't, in which case they get a snapshot with all the information replaced with random substitutes. Don't think switching labels is a good solution, because it isn't.

Comment: This is purely academic but you are correct, this is not the complete process of data sanitisation, it's one of the steps. Certain fields must be masked, some replaced with random data also to avoid sending messages to real people. This process really depends on the organisation - how many people have access to production, which tables, etc, but you'll find that if you have a test table with user actions, anyone with read only access to the real users table in production can determine who did what. Shuffling just the user_id column in such a table can maintain your users privacy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind around **some of the table data cannot be processed** (depends on table size, expect 50% row cannot be processed), here's a solution:

#### Original Table

```
id  name
1   Some
2   Body
3   Once
4   Told
5   Me
6   The
7   World
8   Is
9   Gonna
10  Roll
11  Me
12  I 
13  Ain't
14  The 
15  Shapest
16  Tool
17  In
18  The
19  Shed
20  She
21  was
22  looking
23  kind
24  of
25  dumb
26  with
27  her
28  finger
29  and
30  her
31  thumb
```

#### Query:

```
SELECT new_id, name FROM (
    SELECT  new_id, name FROM (
        SELECT new_meme.id as new_id, original_meme.id as original_id, original_meme.name FROM meme original_meme
        JOIN meme new_meme ON new_meme.id <>  original_meme.id
        ORDER BY RAND()
    ) layer1
    GROUP BY layer1.new_id
) layer2 GROUP BY name
```

#### Result (different every run of course)

```
1   I 
2   In
3   Gonna
4   Ain't
5   The
6   her
7   finger
8   Some
9   dumb
10  She
15  Me
16  with
17  Told
18  and
19  World
21  Roll
22  The 
25  Tool
26  Shed
27  Is
28  Me
29  Sharpest
31  The
```

Note: You might find the query **very slow**, this is because **it join the table twice**, so if data size is 1000, it will need to process 1000 * 1000.

You can control the speed of the query by chaging `ON new_meme.id <>  original_meme.id` to `ON new_meme.id BETWEEN original_meme.id - 5 AND original_meme.id +5` (the 5 can be change), but it will decrease randomness and not worked for non-numberical id

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE table1 SET fname=(SELECT t.fname FROM(SELECT fname FROM table1) t ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: This is not a shuffle code because it doesn't guarantee that all the values in the original column will show in the result. All the original values need to be there, just in a different order.