# Assigning one-column subquery to column

Tags: mysql

So I've got a table with a primary key `id` and a foreign key `target_id` that points to an `id`. What I'm trying to do is set each `target_id` to a random `id`, that is not itself.

At the moment, this is how I get the randomized id's:

```
SELECT id FROM (SELECT id FROM test) AS sub ORDER BY RAND()
```

However, when I try to assign that subquery of randomized id's to the column `target_id`, an error is thrown saying that the subquery returns more than one row.

However, when I tried

```
UPDATE SET `target_id` = `id`
```

to see if columns can be directly copied, it worked, showing that IS possible. But why can't one column of my subquery be copied into a column of my table?

Sorry if I worded my question really weirdly; I'm not very experienced in MySql :/

Thanks! :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18518594/2610061

Answer (score 0):

As you might guess from [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18518594/2610061) in my comment to your question - I did not have time to explain further at the time ... - I assume that what you *actually* want is to shuffle the values of column `target_id` around. In Mysql this seems to be a non-trivial task, as [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18518594/2610061) in my comment shows.

I also played around a bit further and came up with this "variation of the theme" using user defined variables. I first tried using a temporary table, but this can only be referenced once so I had to revert to using a "conventional" table `tmp` in the end:

```
drop table if exists tmp;
select @n:=0;select @m:=0;
create table tmp select * from
  (select *,@n:=@n+1 nr 
   from (select id,@m:=@m+1 n from tbl order by rand()) rnd 
   order by rand()
  ) rnd ; 

update tbl s 
  inner join tmp a on a.id=s.id
  inner join tmp b on b.nr=a.n
  inner join tbl t on t.id=b.id
set t.target_id=s.target_id;
```

Check out the little demo here: http://rextester.com/XYF73480